# pdf image zoom for Kindle

Tags: pdf, ebook

Is it possible to write something into a pdf document so that the Kindle can specifically zoom into an embedded (pdf) image? The Kindle has a 'cursor' and can do that with other (non-pdf) books.

I want to do something such as

```
text tex text text

\pdfsetup{ image={plot_1}, image={
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{image_name}
\end{figure}}}

text text text text text
```

with a `\pdfsetup` command similar to hypersetup: Ignored by LaTeX, but put in the pdf document (or something else that works with `\pdfdest`).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. I can't help you with the Kindle, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you know what has to go in the PDF?  If so, I think there's a `\pdfliteral` command to insert stuff ... err ... literally in there.

Comment: I do not know the pdf command either. Maybe someone has a pdf document, where it works?

Comment: This is a PDF question, not really a TeX one, so is 'off-topic' here, it seems